# fovis odometry failed: NO_DATA

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ros-fuerte, fovis

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get 3D odometry data using [fovis](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fovis), but seems it does not work, because I face bunch of errors:

```
    [ERROR] [1383492092.322748950]: fovis odometry failed: NO_DATA
    [ERROR] [1383492112.108683377]: fovis odometry failed: REPROJECTION_ERROR
    [ERROR] [1383492112.464506236]: fovis odometry failed: INSUFFICIENT_INLIERS
    [ERROR] [1383492112.533878210]: TF_NAN_INPUT: Ignoring transform for child_frame_id "/camera_rgb_optical_frame" from authority "/mono_depth_odometer" because of a nan value in the transform (nan nan nan) (nan nan nan nan)
```

First of all, I run `roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, Then I run `rosrun fovis_ros mono_depth_odometer _base_link_frame_id:=/camera_rgb_optical_frame`.

How can I fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97346/fovis-odometry-failed:-no_data/) by [maysamsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/4226/maysamsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First try without giving any parameter. As far as I remember, it worked without any parameter for kinect.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0